# Constructing infinitely many automorphisms of a free group on two generators to itself

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, automorphism-group

I want to use the universal property of the free group on two generators $F =
F(\{a, b\})$ to construct infinitely many automorphisms of $F$, with the restriction that are not they are not inner automorphisms.

Comment: Indeed to understand the universal property, you need to have a clear idea of the meaning of "extend". If you have sets $X\subset Y$ and $Z$, and a map $f:X\to Z$, a map $g:Y\to Z$ **extends** $f$ if its restriction to $X$ equals $f$. Here this applies to $Y=F$ and $X=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: If you want something concrete, consider the maps $a\mapsto a, b\mapsto ba^n$, $n\in {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Why is it not ok to define an arbitrary map, e.g. why is $a \mapsto a^n$, $b \mapsto b^n$ not ok?

Comment: @TimHowell Because it won't necessarily extend to an automorphism (that is an isomorphism/bijection).

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known that $Aut(F_2)/Inn(F_2)\cong GL_2(\Bbb Z)$, see
[Bogopolski](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwiQ1OGRjpTmAhULAxAIHXxFBAIQFjADegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Freh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de%2F~bogopolski%2FArtikel%2F2000.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0nZJKKSW-VB-KwkzqFFNwT).